# How to read integers from a column of an html table in bash

Tags: bash

I have an html table:

```
<table>
  <tr><td colspan=2>"some text"</td><td>"last week"</td><td>"current week"</td><td>"Delta"</td></tr>
  <tr><td>"some text"</td><td>"some text"</td><td>integer</td><td>integer</td><td>integer</td></tr>
  <tr><td>"some text"</td><td>"some text"</td><td>integer</td><td>integer</td><td>integer</td></tr>
  <tr><td>"some text"</td><td>"some text"</td><td>integer</td><td>integer</td><td>integer</td></tr>
  <tr><td>"some text"</td><td>"some text"</td><td>integer</td><td>integer</td><td>integer</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to extract every integer from the "current week" column, so the second integer from every line (without the first line - header line).

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Have you consider using a better tool? python, ruby, php, perl, ...

Comment: integer=`awk '/"some text"/{getline; print}' $last_report_name | grep -o [0-9]*, but this returns me the first column with integers, not the second one

Comment: This is the current environment and for the moment I need to use bash.

Comment: Consider to use an XML parser like `xmllint`.

Comment: @fedorqui Not a good idea to parse HTML *with regex*. Nothing wrong with parsing HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

#### INPUT HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
        <table> <tr>
                <td colspan="2">"some text"</td>
                <td>"last week"</td>
                <td>"current week"</td>
                <td>"Delta"</td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td>"some text"</td>
                <td>"some text"</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td>"some text"</td>
                <td>"some text"</td>
                <td>integer</td>
                <td>integer</td>
                <td>integer</td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td>"some text"</td>
                <td>"some text"</td>
                <td>integer</td>
                <td>integer</td>
                <td>integer</td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td>"some text"</td>
                <td>"some text"</td>
                <td>integer</td>
                <td>integer</td>
                <td>integer</td>
            </tr> </table>
    </body></html>
```

#### [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) :

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath "//td[text()='\"current week\"']/following::td[4]/text()" file_or_URL
```

or using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) with numeric position (1 to ... ) : simply :

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath "//tr[2]/td[4]/text()" file_or_URL
```

#### OUTPUT :

```
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue: there is [HTML::TableExtract](http://p3rl.org/HTML::TableExtract)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::TableExtract;

my $te = 'HTML::TableExtract'->new( headers => [ 'current' ] );
$te->parse('<table>...</table>');
my $tab = ($te->tables)[0];
for my $row ($tab->rows) {
    print $row->[0], "\n";
}
```